# Stop applications from launching with wind+NUM shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11-v22h2

In Windows 11 22H2 if I hit the Windows key and a number on the keyboard (i.e. win+1) it launches whatever app is pined in the position on the taskbar. How can I disable this without third-party apps?

Comment: That is not new to Windows 11 and as far as I know built into Windows. You would need a 3rd party app to see if you can change this.

Comment: @John I don't ever remember the windows+num opening programs.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Numlock does not affect the top row numbers on the main keyboard area

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will block the combinations for 1 to 9
(0 doesn't seem to be blockable):

```
#1::
#2::
#3::
#4::
#5::
#6::
#7::
#8::
#9::
return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: As stated I am looking for a solution that does not use 3rd party apps.

Comment: I don't know of any built-in mechanism in Windows that does key-combinations. You can disable any one key entirely with the built-in facility, such as the Windows key, but this would be too general.